# Building B2G on Ubuntu 12.10 x86_64 fails while building gecko

Tags: linker-errors, x86-64, gecko, ubuntu-12.10, firefox-os

I have an error building B2G on Ubuntu 12.10. The **Gecko** build fails searching for **librt**.

The libraries are present on the system ...

```
    $ locate librt.so

    /home/user/src/MOZILLA/B2G/prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/i686-linux-glibc2.7-4.4.3/sysroot/usr/lib/librt.so
    /home/user/src/MOZILLA/B2G/prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/i686-linux-glibc2.7-4.4.3/sysroot/usr/lib/librt.so.1
    /home/user/src/MOZILLA/B2G/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/i686-linux-glibc2.7-4.6/sysroot/usr/lib/librt.so
    /home/user/src/MOZILLA/B2G/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/i686-linux-glibc2.7-4.6/sysroot/usr/lib/librt.so.1
    /home/user/src/MOZILLA/B2G/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.7-4.6/sysroot/usr/lib/librt.so
    /home/user/src/MOZILLA/B2G/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.7-4.6/sysroot/usr/lib/librt.so.1
    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1
    /lib32/librt.so.1
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so
```

... but the building process fails ...

```
    $ ./build.sh -j1 gecko

    TEST-PASS | check-sync-dirs.py | /home/user/src/MOZILLA/B2G/gecko/js/src/config <= /home/user/src/MOZILLA/B2G/gecko/config
    /home/user/src/MOZILLA/B2G/prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/i686-android-linux-4.4.3/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-android-linux/4.4.3/../../../../i686-android-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lrt
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any idea ??

Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been discussed on the B2G Github account; https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/B2G/issues/181

It seems like the x86 builds are no longer supported and that you'll need to build for ARM.

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla suggests to use Ubuntu 12.04 x64 to build Gecko